# Symfony2 : Is it possible that collect forms from "many" side entity of "manyToOne"?

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

EDIT: Breakdown

Two or more time is recorded to one day.
There are Date Entity and Time Entity.
Date Entity oneToMany: Time Entity.
Time Entity manyToOne: Date Entity.

[image: step1]

The field of form is added by javascript.

[image: step2]

So far, so good. It does work all right.

The problem is that a category is registered with time.

[image: step3]

```
$form  = $this->createForm(new DateType(), new Date());
```

Structure now looks like this.

```
DateFormType collection with TimeFormType  
    TimeFormType collection with CategoryFormType  
    TimeFormType collection with SubCategoryFormType

Category Entity    oneToMany: Time Entity.  
SubCategory Entity oneToMany: Time Entity.  
Time Entity        manyToOne: Category Entity.  
Time Entity        manyToOne: SubCategory Entity.
```

The bind of form is occurred error at controller, if this condition.

```
$form->bind($request); // => Error: Category, array given 
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...\Entity\Time::setCategory() must be an instance of ...\Entity\Category, array given
```

Can "Category" by which relation was carried out be collected by "manyToOne"?
Is how to use "collection of forms" wrong?

The details are as follows.

---

I want to achieve what is recording time day by day.
Two or more time is recorded to one day.
The field of form is added by javascript.
An outline is the following although it is difficult to explain that it does not become long.

Entities:

> Date, Category, SubCategory, Time

Date.orm

```
Date:
    oneToMany:
        times:
            targetEntity: Time
            mappedBy: date
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

Time.orm

```
Time:
    // ...
    manyToOne:
        date:
            targetEntity: Date
            inversedBy: times
            joinColumn:
                name: date_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        category:
            targetEntity: Category
            inversedBy: times
            joinColumn:
                name: category_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        sub_category:
            targetEntity: SubCategory
            inversedBy: times
            joinColumn:
                name: sub_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Category.orm

```
Category:
    // ...
    oneToMany:
        times:
            targetEntity: Time
            mappedBy: categoy
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]

    manyToMany:
        subs:
          targetEntity: SubCategory
          inversedBy: main
          joinTable:
            name: main_and_sub
            joinColumns:
                joinColum:
                    name: main_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
            inverseJoinColumns:
                joinColum:
                    name: sub_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
```

SubCategory.orm

```
SubCategory:
    // ...
    oneToMany:
        times:
            targetEntity: Time
            mappedBy: sub_category
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]

    manyToMany:
        main:
            targetEntity: Category
            mappedBy: subs
```

TimeType

```
// ...
$builder->add('category', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new CategoryType(),
    'options' => array(
        'required'  => true,
    ),
    'allow_add'      => true,
    'by_reference'   => false,
    'allow_delete'   => true,
    'prototype'      => true,
    'prototype_name' => '__cat_prot__'
));
$builder->add('subcategory', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new SubCategoryType(),
    'options' => array(
        'required'  => false,
    ),
    'allow_add'      => true,
    'by_reference'   => false,
    'allow_delete'   => true,
    'prototype'      => true,
    'prototype_name' => '__cat_prot__'
));
$builder->add('time', 'time', array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'choice',
));
```

DateType

```
// ...
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'choice',
));
$builder->add('times', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new TimeType(),
    'options' => array(
        'required'  => true,
    ),
    'allow_add'      => true,
    'by_reference'   => false,
    'allow_delete'   => true,
    'prototype'      => true,
    'prototype_name' => '__times_prot__'
));
```

View:

```
{{ form_widget(form.date) }}

<ul id="TIMES" data-prototype="
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.times.vars.prototype.children['category'].vars.prototype.name) | e }}
        <label>Category 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.times.vars.prototype.children['subcategory'].vars.prototype.name) | e }}
        <label>Category 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.times.vars.prototype.time) | e }}
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Remove' class='remove' />">
</ul>
<input type="button" value="add times" class="add-form-field" />
```

javascript

```
var nums = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.add-form-field', function(e){
    var field  = $("#TIMES"),
        data   = field.attr("data-prototype"),
        widget = data.replace(/__cat_prot__/g, 0).replace(/__times_prot__/g, nums),
        newLi  = $('<li></li>').html(widget);
        newLi.appendTo("#TIMES");

    nums += 1;

    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '#TIMES .remove', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Controller:

```
$_date = new Date();
$form  = $this->createForm(new DateType(), $_date);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bind($request);  // => Error: Category, array given
```

> $form->bind($request);  // => Error: Category, array given
>
> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...\Entity\Time::setCategory() must be an instance of ...\Entity\Category, array given

If in this condition, "$form->bind($request)" has a error "Category, array given".

Isn't it well-designed?
Is it better not to use form builder?

The date has times.
A time has a category and a sub category.
A time has to have a category.
A time has not to have a sub category. (not must, nullable)

form data

```
date[date][day]

date[times][0][category][0][name]
date[times][0][subcategory][0][name]
date[times][0][time][hour]
date[times][0][time][minute]

date[times][1][category][0][name]
date[times][1][subcategory][0][name]
date[times][1][time][hour]
date[times][1][time][minute]
```

<strike>I think "date[times][0][category][0][name]" is have to be as "date[times][0][category][name]".</strike>
I think the way of consolidation of the form is wrong.

Comment: check that your javascript is not badly naming your fields / sub fields. By default, the js is dumb and will replace __name__ with 0, 1, 2. If you have embedded prototypes, you'll need to make it smarter.

Comment: Take a lok at option: `prototype_name` for that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#prototype-name

Comment: Explanation was added above.

Comment: you category and subcategory has same prototype name. Couldn't that lead to problems ?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Even if it is same prototype name, it occured same error. `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...\Time::setCategory() must be an instance of ...\Category, array given` "Time" is related "Category" by "manyToOne". But "Category" collection form that is related by "Time" has "allow_add" and it is array. Is a problem that the category field can be increased now? It seems straightforward, but I was more and more puzzled.

Comment: Try to create a request you expect to be valid using curl: `curl -X POST -d "date[times][0][category][0][name]=test" -d "..." http://localhost/...`. If it binds correctly, it's coming from html. Debug what you send using devtools (request payload) and find out which html/js is messing that.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible by the data of the present form structure.  Can "Category" by which relation was carried out be collected by "manyToOne"?  Is how to use "collection of forms" wrong?

Comment: a collection will always send an array `category[0][...]=&categeory[1][...]=`

Comment: Is it possible that collect forms from "many" side entity of "manyToOne"? The reason I would think so, "many" side entity has not a "ArrayCollection". So I think there is a way of collection the other.

Comment: you can still make your model feed the inverse collection maybe. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#synchronizing-bidirectional-collections